# Upload Ajax file in yii2

Tags: php, ajax, yii2

I want to upload file using Ajax in yii2 framework
this is my code, but in controller "get Instance" return null because of serialize data; how can i do this?

This is my controller:

```
<?php
public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
            $model = Signature::findOne([
                'user_id' => $id,
            ]);
            if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
                $model->file = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'file');
                $model->file->saveAs('uploads/signature/' . $model->user_id . '.' . $model->file->extension);
                $model->url = 'uploads/signature/' . $model->user_id . '.' . $model->file->extension;

                if ($model->save()) {
                    echo 1;
                } else {
                    echo 0;
                    echo $model->file;
                }
            } else {
                return $this->renderAjax('update', [
                    'model' => $model,
                ]);
            }
    }
?>
```

This is my script code
I can't get my file in controller and it return null

```
<?php $script = <<<JS

$('form#{$model->formName()}').on('beforeSubmit', function(e)
{
    var \$form = $(this);

    $.post(
    \$form.attr("action"),
    \$form.serialize(),

    )
        .done(function(result){
        if(result == 1)
        {
            $(document).find('#update_signature_modal').modal('hide');
            $.pjax.reload({container:'#branchesGrid'});
            //alert();
        } else {
            alert(result);
        }
        }).fail(function()
        {
            console.log("server error");
        });
        return false;
});

JS;
$this->registerJs($script);
?>
```

Comment: maybe you forgot enctype="multipart/form-data"

Comment: You can upload files via AJAX using FormData.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392344/sending-multipart-formdata-with-jquery-ajax

Answer (score 8):

[Please refer here first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35438584/upload-via-ajax-in-yii2-not-including-files/35441854#35441854)

**The Problem**

What the problem in ajax is that `$_FILES` details are not sent in asynchroous request.
When we submit the filled form without ajax request and debug in backend side in PHP by

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_FILES); 
print_r($_POST); 
echo '</pre>';
die;
```

then we successfuly get `$_FILES` and `$_POST` data.

But when we debug the same thing in ajax request, we get only `$_POST` values and we get `$_FILES` as `NULL`. This led us to conclusion that `$_FILES` data are not sent in ajax request by our above code.

**The Solution**

We need to use [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FormData) of JavaScript.

What does it do?

In simple words, it adds all necessary information of file which needs to be uploaded to `data` param in `$.ajax` OR fill up `$_FILES` as well as all `$_POST` data ie non file input such as strings number etc.

In your view file

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']]) ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'title') ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'imageFile')->fileInput() ?>    
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success subm">Upload</button>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

<script>
$('.subm').click(function(e){
    var formData = new FormData($('form')[0]);
    console.log(formData);
    $.ajax({
        url: "some_php_file.php",  //Server script to process data
        type: 'POST',

        // Form data
        data: formData,

        beforeSend: beforeSendHandler, // its a function which you have to define

        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        },

        error: function(){
            alert('ERROR at PHP side!!');
        },


        //Options to tell jQuery not to process data or worry about content-type.
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });
});
</script>
```

**Testing**

Now make ajax request and debug in PHP code by `print_r()` as shown above, you will notice that `$_FILES` is not NULL and its contains all file (which needs to be uploaded) data. And if it is set you can upload using `move_uploaded_file()` funtion

So this is how you file is uploaded via Ajax.

[Referece 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21044798/how-to-use-formdata-for-ajax-file-upload)

[Referece 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously)

[Referece 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23980733/jquery-ajax-file-upload-php)

Comment: Great! You saved me hours. These magic `cache`, `contentType` and `processData` really important for this method to work.

Comment: By adding `cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false` I am getting `PHP Notice 'yii\base\ErrorException' with message 'Undefined variable: model'` error

Answer (score 3):

Use **FormData** to get the instance of file/image type data

```
$( '#my-form' )
  .submit( function( e ) {
    $.ajax( {
      url: 'http://host.com/action/',
      type: 'POST',
      data: new FormData( this ),
      processData: false,
      contentType: false
    } );
    e.preventDefault();
  } );
```